# Finding the Intersection of two known integer sets

Tags: generating-functions, integers

The two sets I am hoping to intersect are the set of [triangle numbers](https://oeis.org/A000217) and [quarter-squares](https://oeis.org/A002620). From those linked resources I have the generating function for both sets.

$$f_{A000217}(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^3} $$
$$f_{A002620}(x) = \frac{x^{2}}{((1-x)^{2}\cdot(1-x^{2}))}$$

I'm only starting to grasp generating functions and their uses, but is it possible to use them to find the generating function of their intersection?

Edit: After doing some more digging, I searched the OEIS for the opening few co-members (1, 6, 36, 210...) and found [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A096979), which may be the solution but I have not validated.

$$f_{A002620}(x) = \frac{x}{((1-x)\cdot(1+x)\cdot(1-6\cdot x+x^2))}$$

Comment: Not really what you're after, but if we call the quarter-squares $q_n$, then for even $n$, you're just looking at square triangular numbers; for odd $n$, you get a Pell-type equation. The Wikipedia page for square triangular numbers has a generating function; you might be able to reverse engineer something from that. The function given is $\frac{1+x}{(1-x)\left(x^2-34x+1\right)}$. Quite a surprising $34$ there!

Comment: Added an edit for a sequence that is called "Sum of the areas of the first n+1 Pell triangles". I don't know anything about Pell triangles or equations so I have some learning to do.